# Sobrecarga de operador de atribuição retorna uma referência C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estou com dúvidas com relação à sobrecarga de operadores da linguagem C++. Não consegui compreender porque a sobrecarga do operador de atibuição retorna uma referência, se eu dou um `return *this` (ao meu entendimento) ele faz o processo de derreferência e retorna o conteúdo não o endereço. Poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Não consegui compreender porque a sobrecarga do operador de atibuição retorna uma referência.

Não necessariamente, fica a escolha do programador.

> se eu dou um return *this (ao meu entendimento) ele faz o processo de 
>   derreferência e retorna o conteúdo não o endereço.

No caso se retorno for uma referencia, não, retorna apenas a referencia.

Vejamos um simples caso:

```
struct complex
{
   float real = 0, imaginario = 0;
   complex& operator=(float real_val);
};

complex& complex::operator=(float real_val)
{
   real = real_val;
   imaginario = 0;
   retuen *this;
}
```

Pelo simples facto do operador retornar uma referencia voce poderá fazer:

```
complex a, b;
a = (b = 10); //não precisa dos parenteses
```

Porque `b = 10` retorna uma referencia para `b` (não uma cópia do valor de `b`), `a` é inicializado com o valor de `b`.